# Google Cloud Platform - Vertex AI training with custom data format

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ocr, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I need to train a custom OCR in vertex AI. My data with have folder of cropped image, each image is a line, and a csv file with 2 columns: image name and text in image.
But when I tried to import it into a [dataset](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/training/using-managed-datasets) in vertex AI, I see that image dataset only support for classification, segmentation, object detection. All of dataset have fixed number of label, but my data have a infinite number of labels(if we view text in image as label), so all types doesn't match with my requirement. Can I use vertex AI for training, and how to do that ?

Comment: Have you considered using Google Cloud's [Vision API](https://cloud.google.com/vision) for performing [OCR](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr)? If yes, can you let me know why it does not suit your use case?

Comment: @KabilanMohanraj I am training an OCR with ancient symbol, so google can't handle it. So I need to create a new OCR model by myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Vertex AI managed datasets do not support OCR applications, you can train and deploy a custom model using Vertex AI’s training and prediction services.

I found a good [article](https://medium.com/geekculture/building-a-complete-ocr-engine-from-scratch-in-python-be1fd184753b) on building an OCR system from scratch. This OCR system is implemented in 2 steps

1. Text detection
2. Text recognition

Please note that this article is not officially supported by Google Cloud.

Once you have tested the model locally, you can train the same on Vertex AI using the [custom model training service](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/training/custom-training). Please follow this [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/vertex_custom_training_prediction) for step-by-step instructions on training and deploying a custom model.

Once the training is complete, the model can be deployed for inference using a [pre-built container](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/predictions/pre-built-containers) offered by Vertex AI or a [custom container](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/predictions/custom-container-requirements) based on your requirements. You can also choose between batch predictions for synchronous requests and online predictions for asynchronous requests.